# Converting Do While Looping to For Next Looping

Tags: vb.net, coding-style

I needed help converting this code type from `Do Loop While` and `Do While Loop` to `For...Next` looping. I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express as the program to run these codes and would greatly appreciate  if anyone could help me. Below is the code that needs to be converted to the For...Next looping type. Once again thank you to anyone who can help.

```
Private Sub btnDo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDo.Click  
   Dim intNum, intSum As IntegerDo  
   intSum += intNum    ‘accumulator/running total  
   intNum += 2        ‘update intNum   
   Loop While (intNum <= 50)  
       Me.lblDoAnswer.Text = intSum.ToString  
End Sub

Private Sub btnDoWhile_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)      Handles btnDoWhile.Click Dim intNum, intSum As Integer    
   Do While (intNum <= 50)  
       intSum += intNum    ‘accumulator/running total  
       intNum += 2        ‘update intNum  
   Loop  
   Me.lblDoWhileAnswer.Text = intSum.ToString  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
For intNum As Integer = 0 To 50 Step 2
    intSum += intNum    ‘accumulator/running total
Next
```

Note: `Step 2` is the equivalent of the `intNum += 2` syntax you had in the `Do` loop.